# Is there a Maupertuis principle for General Relativity?

Tags: general-relativity, lagrangian-formalism, variational-principle, action, geodesics

The motion of a point particle in classical mechanics is given by Newton's equation, $\mathbf{F}=m\mathbf{a}$. Suppose all forces considered are conservative and we have a constant total energy $h$. Let $M$ be the configuration space of our system, $T^*M$ its cotangent bundle, $(\mathbf{q},\mathbf{p})$ the natural coordinates on $T^*M$ and $\gamma$ a curve connecting the start- and end-points of our particle's motion. Then $\int_\gamma \mathbf{p}\,\mathrm{d}\mathbf{q}$ is a viable action integral. The Maupertuis theorem states that 
$$\int_\gamma\mathbf{p}\,\mathrm{d}\mathbf{q}=\sqrt{2}\int_\gamma\mathrm{d}\rho,$$
where $\mathrm{d}\rho$ is the Riemannian metric given by 
$$\mathrm{d}\rho=\sqrt{h-U(\mathbf{q})}\,\mathrm{d}s,$$
$\mathrm{d}s$ is the standard metric on $M$ and $U(\mathbf{q})$ the potential energy. This implies that

$$\text{Newtonian mechanics $\Longleftrightarrow$ geodesic problem of some pair $(M,\mathrm{d}\rho)$}$$

The motion of a point particle in general relativity is given by the equation
$$F=a\tag{1}$$
where $a:=\nabla_{\dot\gamma}\dot\gamma$, $\gamma$ is the path of the particle, $\nabla$ is the Levi-Civita connection of the spacetime $(\mathcal{M},g)$, and $F$ is some "force" 4-vector. $F$ can be seen as an obstruction to the geodesy of $\gamma$, since $a=0$ is just the geodesic equation. (In the same way, $\mathbf{F}$ is an obstruction to geodesy on $\mathbb{R}^n$ since $\mathbf{a}=0$ $\Leftrightarrow$ $\mathbf{x}$ is a straight line and $U(\mathbf{q})$ in the case of constrained Lagrangian mechanics.) (Proofs of the above statements of classical mechanics can be found in Arnold, V.I. *Mathematical Methods of Classical Mechanics.* Springer, 1989.)

Is there some pair $(\mathcal{M}',g')$ for which the geodesic problem is (1), i.e. a suitable generalization of the Maupertuis principle to relativistic mechanics in curved spacetime?

Comment: What would be the meaning of F (in the relativistic case) is conservative?

Comment: @MBN I do not know. Perhaps $F_\mu=-\partial_\mu U$ for some function $U$. (That might be another question right there.)

Comment: The currently-unchallenged Wikipedia item "Principle of least action" claims that there is, through the "Einstein-Hilbert action".  The actual remarks by Maupertuis that the Wiki cites are much more general, but I believe those made earlier by Liebniz, to whom the article traces that principle, are more specific.

Answer (score 3):

I) We assume OP's question concerns a massive point particle of rest mass
$m_0>0$ in a Lorentzian spacetime manifold $(M,g)$ [of signature
$(+,-,\ldots, -)$] between an initial and a final spacetime point $p_i,
p_f\in M$, which should be causally connected. Let us work in units where the speed of light $c=1$ and rest mass $m_0=1$ are both one.

II) Before discussing [Maupertuis's
principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maupertuis'_principle), we should
first have a [stationary action
principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_action) (SAP).
OP's question mentions an unspecified $4$-force. To have a variational principle, we must demand that that $4$-force comes from a potential $U$. The
action is then

$$ S[x;\lambda_i,\lambda_f]
~=~\int_{\lambda_i}^{\lambda_f}\! d\lambda~L, \qquad  L~=~T-U, $$ 
$$\tag{1} T~:=~-\sqrt{T_0},\qquad T_0~:=~ g_{\mu\nu}\dot{x}^{\mu}\dot{x}^{\nu},  
$$

where $\lambda$ is a parameter, and dot means differentiation wrt. $\lambda$.

III) In the SAP, we impose Dirichlet boundary conditions (BC)

$$\tag{2} x^{\mu}(\lambda_i)~=~x_i^{\mu}\qquad\text{and}\qquad x^{\mu}(\lambda_f)~=~x_f^{\mu}, $$

and keep $\lambda_i,\lambda_f$ fixed.

IV) We'll assume that the action (1) is reparametrization invariant

$$\tag{3}\lambda\quad\longrightarrow\quad \tilde{\lambda}~=~f(\lambda), $$

since physics should be geometric.

V) The Lagrangian $4$-momentum and energy function become

$$\tag{4} p_{\mu}~:=~\frac{\partial L}{\partial\dot{x}^{\mu}}~=~ -\frac{g_{\mu\nu}\dot{x}^{\nu}}{\sqrt{T_0}}-\frac{\partial U}{\partial\dot{x}^{\mu}},$$

and

$$\tag{5} h~:=~ p_{\mu}\dot{x}^{\mu} - L~=~\left(1 - \dot{x}^{\mu}\frac{\partial }{\partial\dot{x}^{\mu}}\right)U, $$
respectively.

VI) Usually when discussing the [abbreviated action principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maupertuis'_principle), it is assumed that the Lagrangian (1) has *no* explicit $\lambda$-dependence, so that the energy (5) is conserved on-shell. No explicit $\lambda$-dependence may sound natural & innocent, but together with the reparametrization invariance (3), it severely restricts the possible potentials $U$. The Lorentz potential $U\propto A_{\mu}\dot{x}^{\mu}$ is still allowed, of course.

VII) In fact, no explicit $\lambda$-dependence & reparametrization invariance (3) basically imply that the energy function (5) vanishes identically.

VIII) The [abbreviated action](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maupertuis'_principle) becomes

$$\tag{6} A[x;E,\lambda_i,\lambda_f]
~=~\int_{\lambda_i}^{\lambda_f}\! d\lambda~ p_{\mu}\dot{x}^{\mu}$$

for virtual paths of constant and the same energy

$$ \tag{7} h~=~E, $$

satisfying Dirichlet BC (2), but free $\lambda_i$ and $\lambda_f$. From Section VII, we know that the energy $E=0$ drops out of the abbreviated action (6).

IX) Returning to OP's question, there seems little hope to achieve a Jacobi square root form of the abbreviated action principle (6) without further assumptions.

The natural next step is to assume that the potential $U$ does *not* depend on the $4$-velocity $\dot{x}^{\mu}$. Then the energy function $h\equiv U$ becomes just the potential energy, and $p_{\mu}\dot{x}^{\mu}\equiv T\equiv -\sqrt{T_0}$.

However, with all the other above requirements, this basically implies that the potential $U=0$ is zero!

Of course, without a potential $U=0$, we unsurprisingly achieve a Jacobi square root form of the abbreviated action principle

$$\tag{8} A[x;E,\lambda_i,\lambda_f]
~=~-\int_{\lambda_i}^{\lambda_f}\! d\lambda~\sqrt{T_0} .$$

The abbreviated action (8) is identical to the SAP (1) that we started from, essentially due to reparametrization invariance.

Comment: The action integral you gave is the standard integral for geodesic motion on a spacetime. In the OP I'm asking for an action integral for nongeodesic motion on $(\mathcal{M},g)$ posed as geodesic motion on some other $(\mathcal{M}',g')$. As such, this does not (appear to) answer the question.

Comment: Oh, I didn't notice the $4$-force. I updated the answer.