# Can we always effectively describe a timelike worldline (non-geodesic) in one spacetime as a geodesic in some other spacetime?

Tags: general-relativity

Can we always effectively describe a timelike worldline (non-geodesic) in one spacetime as a geodesic in some other spacetime with a different metric? Is this implied by the equivalence principle saying that acceleration and gravitation are indistinguishable.

Comment: Are you defining geodesic by an action principle or by the geodesic equation?

Comment: geodesic equation @0celo7

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/224876/is-there-a-maupertuis-principle-for-general-relativity, possible duplicate.